# How can I use awk to split a single line into multi lines?

Tags: awk

**Input:**

A mostly tab-delimited file with a variable number of columns. Some rows have another delimiter ';'.

**Output:**

A tab-delimited file with equal columns where rows that have a ';' delimiter are put into a new line.

My input looks like this:

```
chr15   51300184        51300335        Merged-chr15-51300260-2 1       +       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +
chr15   51307793        51308094        Merged-chr15-51307944-3 1       -       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +;chr15   51307694        51333253        CRD_477 1       +
```

What I want is to take the rows that have a ';' delimiter and push that into a new row along with the information in the first 6 columns. The output should look like this:

```
chr15   51300184        51300335        Merged-chr15-51300260-2 1       +       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +
chr15   51307793        51308094        Merged-chr15-51307944-3 1       -       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +
chr15   51307793        51308094        Merged-chr15-51307944-3 1       -       chr15   51307694        51333253        CRD_477 1       +
```

Comment: @Lety this almost works, it doesn't keep the information from the first 6 columns unfortunately, but maybe I can play around with it and figure it out!

Comment: You post that file has tab, but posted it with spaces, fixed.  Can there be more than one `;` on the line?  Its always a good idea to wait some to accept an answer, a better may show up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you:

```
awk  'BEGIN {OFS = "\t";} /;/ {$6=$6";"; print $0} !/;/ {print}' FILENAME | awk -F \; '/;/ { print $1 $2"\n"$1"\t"$3} !/;/ {print}'
```

---

First command:

```
# Set the output field separator to be a tab
BEGIN {OFS = "\t";} 
# If there is a semi-colon in the line, 
# add another semicolon at the end of the 6th field, then print the whole line
/;/ { $6=$6";"; print $0} 
# If no semi-colon, print the line as-is
!/;/ {print}' FILENAME
```

Second command:

```
# Set field separator to be a semicolon
awk -F \; 
# if the line has a semi-colon, take the first token (first 6 fields of initial awk)
# and add it to the front of the second token, followed by a new line, 
# and add it to the front of the third token
/;/ { 
  print $1 $2"\n"$1"\t"$3
} 
# no semi-colon? no problem!
!/;/ {print}
```

The idea is to insert a `;` character to divide the string into the prefix and 2 suffixes which awk can parse easily in the second comand.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: What can be done with two `awk` can normally be done with one `awk`

Comment: You do not need 2 calls to awk and a pipe to do this. Also `/;/ {$6=$6";"; print $0} !/;/ {print}` can be written as just `/;/ {$6=$6";"} {print}`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F';' '{print $1} NF>1{sub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*){5}\+;/,""); print}' file
chr15   51300184        51300335        Merged-chr15-51300260-2 1       +       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +
chr15   51307793        51308094        Merged-chr15-51307944-3 1       -       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +
chr15   51307793        51308094        Merged-chr15-51307944-3 1       -       chr15   51307694        51333253        CRD_477 1       +
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk '{split($0,a,";");print a[1]} a[2] {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[2]}' OFS="\t" file
chr15   51300184        51300335        Merged-chr15-51300260-2 1       +       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +
chr15   51307793        51308094        Merged-chr15-51307944-3 1       -       chr15   51244653        51308019        CRD_476 1       +
chr15   51307793        51308094        Merged-chr15-51307944-3 1       -       chr15   51307694        51333253        CRD_477 1       +
```

It splits the line by `;`.  If there are 2 parts, print 6 first fields and then last part.

If there are more than one `;`, you can use a loop to print them out with data from firs 6 fields like this:

```
awk '{n=split($0,a,";");print a[1]} n>1 {for (i=2;i<=n;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[i]}' OFS="\t" file
```